# Orchard CMS: Using different Layout for Anonymous users

Tags: layout, content-management-system, orchardcms, anonymous

I would like to use a different layout view for anonymous users. I have tried using url alternates and I am not sure how I can create a layout for anonymous users since there is no particular url for them.
The idea is that, if a new user visits the site I want to show a splash screen with very limited information with an option to register/ login to view the full site. This splash screen will have a completely different layout / look and feel from the rest of the site.
I tried using the Anonymous user layer but all I could do was move widgets (maybe I am missing something).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution but you can do something like this to get what you want:

Add new layout in a file with the name of your choosing - for example, you could name it `Splash.cshtml`.

Add the code below to the top of your `Layout.cshtml` template:

```
@if (WorkContext.CurrentUser == null) {
    @Display.Splash()
    return;
}
```

The code will check if the user is logged in. If it's not, it will render the content of your `Splash.cshtml` template, and stop the rendering of the rest of the `Layout.cshtml` template.

If you need to display any of the widgets in your `Splash.cshtml` template, you could add it by simply adding `@Display(Layout.NameOfTheZone)` where you should replace `NameOfTheZone` with the actual name of the zone you're using inside the `Layout.cshtml` template. Generally, anything that you use inside `Layout.cshtml` template with the `Model` object, you can use through `Layout` object inside any of your views.

Comment: Ivan - Thank you very much. I did a test run and it seems to work as expected. I will do some more work later. Thanks you also on the tip on how to add Zones!